# How to get info from a form in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I'm new on Rails and web developping.

I wonder how I can get what's written inside a form.

This is what I have :

```
<form>
<input id="bottom" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
```

What I want now is to get and save what written in the input, but I don't know how do to do it with rails.

Comment: Where do you want to have this information, server or client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a route and map it to the controller. Use the defined route in the action.
2. in the controller you can access the values as `params[:input_name]`. Replace input_name with the corresponding values.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to install 'pry' gem which allows you to write 'binding.pry' somewhere in the code (in your case you should add this line to your controller 'create' action which is responsible for the page where is your form located).

What will happen? Whenever you press submit button, you go to console and see that it shows you a 'create' action. Then you can type 'params' and press 'enter' and you will see how is the data from form stored.

The 'pry' gem is really essential assistant for Rails developing. You can paste 'binding.pry' at any point to check what is happening.

Comment: Oh that's nice! I didn't know about this `pry` ! Thanks a lot !